# What hinge to use for hidden raisable notebook platform on desk

Tags: carpentry, hinges

as many of us now days I am stuck working from home these days. As my appartement was never designed for this, I do not have dedicated computer desk and I am stuck with using dining table as my workplace. But neither I nor my wife are happy with computer and cables cluttering this space in living room and I am thinking of concealing the computer inside of the desk while not in use.

I was thinking of cutting hole in the desk in size of the computer, mounting some platform under the hole to place computer on top of it for it to sink in. While the computer will not be in use, it will be covered with peace of plywood to cover the hole. But to for the plywood to be flush with the desk, the computer needs to be little lower then it would be comfortable for me to work on in. So I am thinking of some sort of hinge system which would rise the platform 1cm or 2 while the computer is in use, and lower it while its closed. And I prefer the mechanism under the table to be as small as possible not to bother people sitting by the desk while it is closed.

I hope it is understandable, for better clarity a created a small diagram, and I am attaching picture of the table, hope it helps. I would be thankful for any tips or direction on where to research into it.

[image]

[image]

Big Thanks

Comment: Is that an Ikea style desk?  It may be hollow, and not something you can easily cut a hole in or attach brackets to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. It is custom made hardwood table. I did try to shorten ikea table once and know what you have in mind :)

Comment: I would think long and hard before cutting a hole in a _custom made_ table top and filling it with a piece of plywood. I mean, sure, you could get a small project panel of 1/4" walnut veneer ply, but have you looked at the price of lumber lately? Especially for what we all pray will be a temporary situation. Of course, it's you, not me...

Comment: It's a notebook... Get a case or backpack then fold it up and put it away when you're done. Cables, peripherals and all.

Comment: I would just put the laptop on a serving tray you can move without juggling cables, which also doubles as a lap desk to boot.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to what you are thinking but I'd leave the table as is and look into either getting a basket on slides that you can attach to the bottom of the table and stick the computer in there when you are't using it. You can just pull it out when needed.

Or a floor magazine holder or similar. You can just drop the computer in it when not in use. I do this with a number of work computers.

Also, you never know when you'll have to go back to the office and you've just made a hole in your table you no longer have use for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback, I was considering this. Problem with this for me is, that I could easily store the computer to shelf which is 2m away, but never do it :) So I am worried putting it to the drawer would not make a difference. Doing something as easy as closing the lit seemed more probable

Answer (score 2):

There are various problems with this.

1. Instead of needing a place to put your laptop when it is not in use, you need a place to put a laptop-sized piece of plywood when the laptop is in use.
2. If you spill something while eating you might ruin your laptop.

Consider instead a solution that manages only the cables.  When you are finished working, unplug the laptop and put it away.  You can attach something to the wall for that if you want.  *Buy* a cable-trough solution that you can build into your tabletop.  It only needs small lid, made from the piece you cut out, on ordinary hinges.  You put the PSU and all cables inside it, supply it with power from underneath the table, and when you want to use it you just pull the wires out and plug in your laptop.

You can cut very small notches in the cover so it can be closed while the cables are in use.

[image]

You could make this by mounting a project box (without the lid) under the table, placing a power bar inside it, cutting a rectangular piece from the table top, cleaning up its edges and putting it back with a piano hinge.

[image]
[image]
[image]

the power bar and your laptop PSUs would remain inside the box all the time.  The power bar would run under the table to an outlet.

Comment: Hey, thank you for lengthy answer. 1: I was thinking to put some velcro strips on the lid and top of the computer, so when the computer would be opened, the lid would be attached to the back of the monitor. And when the computer would not be home, the lid could stay on the table. 2: spill might be an issue, I did not consider this.

Comment: What you proposed is something similar to what I have in mind as backup plan. I am considering some ikea hanging cable manager under the table with cable-trough opening like this one https://webshop.schachermayer.com/cdn/derivates/5/133/835/DV005-ppic_Kabeldurchgang_rund_Holz_eiche_356093_0.jpg. Although it would be great not have the computer visible on the table